# How to display data from array json in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, handlebars.js

Below is the json from server I want to print only name form customer list

```
var PatientList = [{
  "Customer": [{
    "phone": 1234567890,
    "name": "customer"
  }],
  "Patients": [{
    "age": null,
    "relationship": null,
    "id": 5,
    "weight": null,
    "name": "customer"
  }],
  "Lead": [{
    "source": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "service": 3
  }]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each PatientList}}
  {{#each Customer}}
    <div>{{name}}</div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```